# which visual studio project type should i choose that will best for standart c library

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

which visual studio project type should i choose that will best for  c basic library(uni studies).

the problem in visual studio 2010 express that its gives _tmain instead int main().

Thanks

Comment: If you want to develop C, you really should choose something other than VS, as it does not support modern standards and purportedly never will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually select "Win32 Console Application" and then "Empty project". Add a new source file and type in the main() by hand.

I have no idea what R is talking about with his absurd comment.